# php jwt token authentication failed to apple store connect api

Tags: php, jwt

As per below forum link reference :

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119705, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117754

I try to connect **app-store-connect** (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi) using PHP but getting below error each time  :

```
   stdClass Object

   (

     [errors] => Array

    (

          [0] => stdClass Object

          (

           [status] => 401

           [code] => NOT_AUTHORIZED

           [title] => Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.

           [detail] => Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens

          )

    )

  )
```

Please check my below code once and my php xammp version 7.4 :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

$strKey=file_get_contents("./AuthKey_##########.p8");

$strUrl = "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users";

$dHeader = array("kid" => "##########", "typ" => "JWT");

$strHeader = json_encode($dHeader);

$strBase64Header = base64url_encode($strHeader);

$dPayLoad = array("iss" => "69a#####-####-####-####-############", "exp"=>time()+1200, "aud"=>"appstoreconnect-v1");

$strPayLoad = json_encode($dPayLoad);

$strBase64PayLoad = base64url_encode($strPayLoad);

$strContent = $strBase64Header . '.' . $strBase64PayLoad;

$strAlgName = "sha256";

$strSignature = base64url_encode(hash_hmac($strAlgName, $strContent, $strKey));

$strToken = $strBase64Header . '.' . $strBase64PayLoad . '.' . $strSignature;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/users",

  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",

  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,

  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,

  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,

  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",

  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(

    "Authorization: Bearer ".$strToken

  ),

));



$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo "<pre>";

if ($err) {

  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err."<br>";

   print_r(json_decode($response));

} else {

  print_r(json_decode($response));

}

function base64url_encode($data) {

  return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');

}
```

Please provide details code if I did mistake in above .

Answer (score 0):

You’re using “sha256” algorithm for you signature but App Store Connect API keys are ES256 keys. Change your signing algorithm or, to simplify things, use a JWT library. You can find several php options at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). Be sure to choose one that supports ES256.